# ASP.NET: How to show search results splitted in a page number list

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm making a e-commerce website, I have a page dedicated to search items in the shop.
In some cases when I search for some key words I get lists that can be of more thatn 100 items, th eproblem is that the page gets relatively long.

So I was wondering if there is a way to split all the search results in n pages programmatically like a tipical search in google, where all the extra seach pages are listed at bottom of the page.

What is the best practice? any good tips on topics to study? 
elegant solutions are well accepted...

By the way my site is in ASP.net c#, data comes from sql server.

Comment: Are you planning on using a datagrid or a repeater. The Datagrid has it built in but I have never actually done it

Comment: I have no clue how to do it I'll check your suggestions

Comment: @logixologist, from memory the paging in Datagrid works fine even though it's very simplistic. It usually involves loading the full dataset from the DB (assuming you're using one) and letting the Datagrid slice it into pages.

Comment: btw I'm clearly using a DB

Comment: Right, then Datagrid is a good place to start. If and when you run into its limitations, you can build something better yourself. Search for "ASP.NET datagrid tutorial" to get started.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can do.

You can either add the PagedList extension from Nugget Package Manager or use Linq to SQL Entity Framework to do it.

I'm not sure which method you're using to connect to the database, but if you're using Entity Framework database first, here's what you can do.  Assuming that you're using MVC Framework and you would like to return 10 items per page.

```
public ActionResult MethodName(int page=1)
 {
   SQLServerDatabaseEntities entity = new SQLServerDatabaseEntities();
   List<NameOfEntity> models = entity.DBSetPropertyName
                               .OrderBy(n=>n.PropertyNameFromTheEntity)
                               .Skip((page - 1) * 10) 
                               .Take(10).ToList();
       //Add the information about what the method should do.
   return View(models);
 }
```

It would have been much simpler and easier if you provided code sample.

Comment: It's never to late to answer :-) (1-2 year), yep the solution you are suggesting is the one I'm using at the moment.